# Let putty watch for specific output in stdout and notify

Tags: notifications, console, putty

Do you know any way to introduce a notification feature to putty client? I would like to setup some regular expressions or simply text strings and be notified (by sound or some tooltip) when this content appears in stdout.

If not specific in putty, how can I get it done?

There used to be a similar feature in older version of KDE's konsole terminal, but even now I can't see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [PuTTY source code](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) is available for download or Subversion access.  [It is licenced](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/licence.html) under the MIT licence, so you are welcome to modify the source (or pay someone to modify the source for you) to add such a notification feature directly to the client.

Depending on what you need, exactly, it may be simpler to rig up a solution like @Ignacio's answer suggests (using *tail* or other console utilities).  If your client system is running an X-server, and you connected with X forwarding enabled in PuTTY, you could even look into using [zenity](http://freshmeat.net/projects/zenity) to give you a pop-up dialog for the notification.

Answer (score 2):

Use `tail -F` to watch the file, and use `awk` to detect the line and generate the output.

Comment: I am already using `tail -f` to watch the log file. How does `awk` or `grep` help to have a notification in client (Windows)?

Comment: With awk you can run a custom command when the line is matched. If this is not good enough then PuTTY won't do.